# Why python 2.7.2 does not have a symbolic link in /usr/lib/python2.7

Tags: python, macos, mercurial, osx-snow-leopard, python-2.7

I broke my Mercurial install . So I reinstalled Python-2.7 on 64-bit Mac Os 10.6 ( Snow Leopard ) with python-2.7.2-macosx10.6.dmg .
I have the folder /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/  . Python 2.7.2 can be interpreted

The folder /usr/lib/python2.6 exits but not python2.7 . It seems the PYTHONPATH variable environment must be set to /usr/lib/python-latest-version

Also I don't have a /Library/Python/2.7  either. It does not seem like  a bad install

How to get this /usr/lib/python2.7 folder right ? Can I create it manually ?

Comment: To users who closed as off topic . Where (on stackexchange sites) should this kind of question be asked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Python framework builds on OS X, in particular the python.org Pythons like you installed, do not use `/usr/lib/python*`.  You can find the location of the standard library and for Distutils-installed site packages using the [sysconfig](http://docs.python.org/library/sysconfig.html) module in the Python standard library:

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.2 (v2.7.2:8527427914a2, Jun 11 2011, 15:22:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7'
>>> sysconfig.get_path('purelib')
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```